# I am getting a 100% accuracy on all my machine learning models. What is wrong with my model

Tags: python, database, scikit-learn

I am working on a dataset that is a collection of 5 Hand made letters. I've uploaded the DB on Kaggle and if anyone wants to give it a look, please do.

https://www.kaggle.com/shayanriyaz/gesture-recognition

Currently, I've trained and tested several models but I keep getting 100% accuracy.

Here's my code.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# importing alll the necessary packages to use the various classification algorithms
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression  # for Logistic Regression algorithm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #to split the dataset for training and testing
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier  # for K nearest neighbours
from sklearn import svm  #for Support Vector Machine (SVM) Algorithm
from sklearn import metrics #for checking the model accuracy
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier #for using Decision Tree Algoithm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import os # accessing directory structure

from subprocess import check_output

df = df.drop(['Id','Time', 'Wrist_Pitch','Wrist_Roll'],axis = 1)
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

nRowsRead = None 

df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/ASL_DATA.csv', delimiter=',', nrows = nRowsRead)

df.dataframeName = 'ASL_DATA.csv'
nRow, nCol = df.shape

print(f'There are {nRow} rows and {nCol} columns')

plt.figure(figsize=(30,20)) 
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),annot=True,cmap='cubehelix_r') #draws  heatmap with input as the correlation matrix calculted by(iris.corr())
plt.show()

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2)# in this our main data is split into train and test
# the attribute test_size=0.3 splits the data into 70% and 30% ratio. train=70% and test=30%
print(train.shape)
print(test.shape)

train_X = train[['Thumb_Pitch','Thumb_Roll','Index_Pitch','Index_Roll','Middle_Pitch','Middle_Roll','Ring_Pitch','Ring_Roll','Pinky_Pitch','Pinky_Roll']]# taking the training data features
train_y=train.Letter# output of our training data
test_X= test[['Thumb_Pitch','Thumb_Roll','Index_Pitch','Index_Roll','Middle_Pitch','Middle_Roll','Ring_Pitch','Ring_Roll','Pinky_Pitch','Pinky_Roll']] # taking test data features
test_y =test.Letter   #output value of test data

from sklearn import preprocessing
mm_scaler = preprocessing.RobustScaler()
train_X = mm_scaler.fit_transform(train_X)
test_X = mm_scaler.transform(test_X)


model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(train_X,train_y)
prediction=model.predict(test_X)
print('The accuracy of the Decision Tree is',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,test_y))


model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(train_X,train_y)
prediction=model.predict(test_X)
print('The accuracy of the Decision Tree is',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,test_y))

model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=) #this examines 3 neighbours for putting the new data into a class
model.fit(train_X,train_y)
prediction=model.predict(test_X)
print('The accuracy of the KNN is',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,test_y))
```

Comment: How is the dataset for training and test. How you did you made the separation?

Comment: Have you tried to apply the same transformations to both train_X and test_X?

Comment: I used the train_test_split function with a test_size of 0.2

Comment: I'm a little confused about which transformations to apply, I used the RobustScaler for this one, so the outliers do not create noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your model, it's just a trivial problem for the models to solve.  These letters look nothing alike when you consider all of the features you have.  If you had chosen all of the letters, or ones that all looked the same, you *might* see some error.

Rerun the model using only index_pitch and index_roll.  You will still get like 95% AUC.  At least by doing that you can guess that the only loss comes from B,D, and K, which by looking at an image of what those look like are the only 3 that could remotely be confused if you only looked at the index finger.  This turns out to be the case.

It's just a problem that given your data set is actually solvable